# Copy picked image through Intent.ACTION_PICK to a file

Tags: android

My code allows the user to pick an image using Intent.ACTION_PICK on click of a button:

```js
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
    photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
    startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, SELECT_PHOTO);  
   }
```

How can I copy this selected image to a file that has been created?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to implement `onActivityResult` which is invoked when your activity resumes from after the user picking the photo from their library.

The intent data will be a `Uri` and you will need to extract the absolute path to the image on disk.

Something like this:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == SELECT_PHOTO  && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        File file = getBitmapFile(data);
        if(file != null) {
          // do something with the file
        }
    }
}


public File getBitmapFile(Intent data) {
  Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
  Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, new String[] { android.provider.MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA }, null, null, null);
  cursor.moveToFirst();

  int idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA);
  String selectedImagePath = cursor.getString(idx);
  cursor.close();

  return new File(selectedImagePath);
}
```

If your user has their Picassa (or any other cloud-based photo services) enabled on their phone, its possible the OS will allow them to pick an image from that source. The problem is that the result of this doesn't adhere to the logic in `getBitmapFile` - that is, its not the same as picking a local file. To get around this you can ensure your Picker intent only allows local files:

`photoPickerIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_LOCAL_ONLY, true);`

To store the Bitmap to another file you will need a couple more methods:

```
private boolean writeBitmapToFile(Bitmap bitmap, File destination) {
    FileOutputStream out = null;
    try {
        out = new FileOutputStream(destination);
        return bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Log.i(TAG, String.format("Error writing bitmap to %s: %s", destination.getAbsoluteFile(), ex.getMessage()));
        return false;
    } finally {
        try {
            if (out != null) {
                out.close();
            }
        }catch (IOException ex) {}
    }
}

private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
    File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    File image = File.createTempFile(imageFileName, ".jpg", storageDir);
    return image;
}
```

To use these methods:

`writeBitmapToFile(bitmap, createImageFile());`

Comment: I want to store this selected image which is in the form of Uri to a temporary file that has been created using image = File.createTempFile(
          imageFileName,  /* prefix */
          ".jpg",         /* suffix */
          storageDir      /* directory */
      );

Comment: thanks @Cody. I was looking for writeBitmapToFile() function.