# Copy picked image to different folder on device

Tags: android

I'm quite new to Android development and this is my first post on Stack Overflow, I hope somebody can help me out.

I want users to pick an image that's already stored on the device, and copy the selected image to a different folder, where I'm already storing images that are taken with the camera. 
But with my code I end up with images of 0 bytes in the preferred folder.

I followed this great post [Copy picked image through Intent.ACTION_PICK to a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28002907/copy-picked-image-through-intent-action-pick-to-a-file/28002960#28002960?newreg=4f33ca832ed3436c9af2720855435c1f) but guess I missed something.

```
private void pickImage() {
        Intent pickImageIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        startActivityForResult(pickImageIntent, GALLERY_REQUEST_CODE);
    }

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            switch (requestCode) {
                case GALLERY_REQUEST_CODE:
                    Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                    String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
                    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                    cursor.moveToFirst();
                    int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                    String selectedImagePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                    cursor.close();
                    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(selectedImagePath);
                    setReducedImageSize();

                    try {
                        writeBitmapToFile(bitmap, createImageFile());
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    break;

                case CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE:
                    setReducedImageSize();
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

private void setReducedImageSize() {
        int targetImageViewWidth = mCapturedImageView.getWidth();
        int targetImageViewHeight = mCapturedImageView.getHeight();

        BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mImageFileLocation, bmOptions);
        int cameraImageWidth = bmOptions.outWidth;
        int cameraImageHeight = bmOptions.outHeight;

        int scaleFactor = Math.min(cameraImageWidth / targetImageViewWidth, cameraImageHeight / targetImageViewHeight);

        bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        bmOptions.inSampleSize = scaleFactor;
        bmOptions.inPurgeable = true;

        Bitmap photoReducedSizeBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mImageFileLocation, bmOptions);
        mCapturedImageView.setImageBitmap(photoReducedSizeBitmap);
    }

private boolean writeBitmapToFile(Bitmap bitmap, File destination) {
        FileOutputStream out = null;
        try {
            out = new FileOutputStream(destination);
            return bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.i(TAG, String.format("Error writing bitmap to %s: %s", destination.getAbsoluteFile(), ex.getMessage()));
            return false;
        } finally {
            try {
                if (out != null) {
                    out.close();
                }
            }catch (IOException ex) {}
        }
    }

private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "EMPL_" + timeStamp + "_";
        File image = File.createTempFile(imageFileName, ".jpg", mGalleryFolder);

        mImageFileLocation = image.getAbsolutePath();
        return image;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace:

```
                Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
                Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                String selectedImagePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                cursor.close();
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(selectedImagePath);
```

with:

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContentResolver().openInputStream(data.getData()));
```

Comment: Thanks for replying! Unfortunately I get a 'Cannot resolve getContentResolver' when I follow your suggestion.

Comment: @JorisvanLaar: Sorry, I missed the parentheses after it. See the updated answer.

Comment: I have edited my code as per your suggestion, as you can see in the adjusted code snippet from my post. It now saves my image to the new folder, thank you!

One strange effect of the new code is that I use setReducedImageSize() to set the selected image on an ImageView to show to the user. But now the ImageView is one image 'behind'. Meaning that it's not showing the last picked image, but the one before that, any thoughts?

Comment: @JorisvanLaar: Please do not make massive replacements in the question like that. Now my answer and our discussion will not make sense to future readers of this page. Either ask a separate question or possibly make an edit showing your new code after the existing code. In terms of your problem, I don't know what `mImageFileLocation` is or most of the other stuff in `setReducedImageSize()` is. Note that you are calling `setReducedImageSize()` before you are saving your `Bitmap` to disk, though.

Comment: I've reverted the code, so everything should be clear for future readers. And you were right about calling setReducedImageSize() too soon, it works now. 
I really appreciate you taking the time to help me!